# Reasons For Slowness in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We are observing intermittent slowness in our SQL Server. We ran sp_who2, sp_who3 stored procedures for checking CPU/IO usage but did not see any spikes/abnormal values. What else could be the possible reasons for slowness. What other reports we can take from SQL Server to analyze the issue?

We are using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Comment: If this is related to queries, then you might want to have a look at this meta Q&A [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/15356).  Is it taking longer than normal to return results?  Is it on the server side or on the client side? What has changed since performance has degraded? Is it an actual Windows Server with SQL Server Express installed on it, or is it a laptop running a local SQL Server Express Edition? If server: shared or dedicated?  Hit [edit] and add as much details as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some examples of queries you're experiencing the slowness with, and their **execution plans** there's not much we have to go off of.

Other good monitoring tools you can use to try to capture something is [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) and [sp_Blitz](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/). You can also check the most commonly occuring [Wait Stats](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/05/sql-performance/introduction-to-wait-statistics) to see if there's anything abnormal there.